# Why some abstract class has spring @Configuration annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-r2dbc

This is an example for the question. (spring-data-r2dbc)

```java
package org.springframework.data.r2dbc.config;

@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public abstract class AbstractR2dbcConfiguration implements ApplicationContextAware {
...
}
```

According to my common sense, an abstract class cannot be registered as a bean even if it has @Configuration.
And since @Configuration does not have @Inherited, the object of the inheriting class is not automatically registered as a bean, so we have to add @Configuration directly for the inheriting class.
I'm curious as to why some abstract class has @Configuration annotation like the code above.

Comment: It might help to know that Spring doesn’t rely on the standard `@Inherited` annotation to automatically inherit annotations from superclasses.  It has its own logic (see e.g. https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils.html) that walks a class’s inheritance tree looking for Spring annotations, whether they’re meta-annotated with `@Inherited` or not.  Spring’s approach also works for annotations on methods and interfaces, unlike `@Inherited` which only inherits class-level annotations from the superclass.

Answer (score 3):

I looked up some information and found that abstract classes are allowed.

The constraints in the documentation do not say that abstract classes or interfaces(can?) do not support Configuration annotations.

[Configuration annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html)

**Constraints when authoring @Configuration classes**

- Configuration classes must be provided as classes (i.e. not as instances returned from factory methods), allowing for runtime enhancements through a generated subclass.
- Configuration classes must be non-final (allowing for subclasses at runtime) unless the proxyBeanMethods flag is set to false in which case no runtime-generated subclass is necessary.
- Configuration classes must be non-local (i.e. may not be declared within a method).
- Any nested configuration classes must be declared as static.
- @Bean methods may not in turn create further configuration classes (any such instances will be treated as regular beans, with their configuration annotations remaining undetected).

Like this question, I hope there are powerful guys who can explain this problem from the perspective of source code.
Because apart from the instructions in the documentation, I don't know what the reason is yet.

---

I tested repeatedly for an afternoon and found that adding Configuration annotations to abstract classes does not seem to have any effect, What seems to be valid is just the annotation on the final subclass.

Here are the codes!!!
first, we need an interface `TestInterface.java`:

```
public interface TestInterface {                                                                         
    public String hello();                                                                                         
    public String hello1();                                                                                        
}
```

then make an abstract class `MyConfigration.java`:

```
//@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
//@Configuration
public abstract class MyConfigration implements TestInterface  {      
    @Bean                                                                       
    public String hello() {                                                     
        System.out.println("call hello in super class");                        
        return "hello";                                                                           
    }                                                                                                                                                 
}
```

and last, we need a subclass `SubMyConfigration.java`

```
@Configuration                                                                  
class SubMyConfigration extends MyConfigration {                              
    @Bean                                                                       
    public String hello1() {                                                    
        return " hello1 from subclass";                                         
    }                                                                           
}
```

use the main method to test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {                                                                                                                               
    ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

    TestInterface configOfInterface = applicationContext.getBean(MyConfigration.class);
    configOfInterface.hello();    
    configOfInterface.hello();                                                       
    configOfInterface.hello1();                                                            
    configOfInterface.hello1(); 
}
```

If add `@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)` on subclass(SubMyConfigration), will print `call hello in super class` 3 times.

If add `@Configuration` on subclass(SubMyConfigration), will print `call hello in super class` 1 times.

Whether to add `@Configuration` annotations to the superclass(MyConfigration) and whether to add `proxyBeanMethods = false` does not affect the number of print times.

According to this part of the code, there are 3 conclusions：

- subclass(`SubMyConfigration`) must add `@Configuration`,otherwise it won't work;
- No matter whether the superclass adds `@Configuration` annotations, and whether the `proxyBeanMethods = false` parameter is added to the annotations, it will not affect the final result.
- The `proxyBeanMethods = false` parameter, only added to the subclass `@Configuration` annotation will affect the result

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I am missing something big here so please feel free to correct me.

> ```
> @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
> public abstract class AbstractR2dbcConfiguration implements ApplicationContextAware
> ```
>
> According to my common sense, an abstract class cannot be registered
> as a bean even if it has @Configuration.

According to my knowledge `@Configuration` is never indended to make the annotated class a spring bean. The main reason it exists is that it is a meta information that spring understands so that it can parse it correctly and search the methods that bring `@Bean` and from those methods it would create spring beans that would be placed inside the spring context.

So even if a class is declared as abstract you don't have any constraint on to define a common method in that abstract class. Then this method could as well be marked with `@Bean` and that would be no problem for spring to inspect it and use the returned object from that method and place it inside the spring context as a bean.